# Android webview - cannot insert text to <input> fields

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, webview

Experienced by users with Jelly bean (4.1) and 2.3

On api level 14 and 15 the problem does not occur.

I can't find any way around this problem...

Comment: Have you set encoding of a site in a proper way? What is your Android dev language?

Comment: I changed the question - it does not relate to the language

Answer (score 1):

This is normally caused by certain CSS properties being applied to your text fields, although that normally only affects 4.0 and up.  What version of PhoneGap are you currently running?

Comment: what css properties do you mean?